# Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in Laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel I make the TrainingRequest File for validation using

```
php artisan make:request TrainingRequest

FatalErrorException in TrainingRequest.php line 3: 

Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first   statement  in the script
```

And I make the validation in that created file as below:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests; <!--This is line number 3 -->

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class TrainingRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

             return [
                'topic' =>  'required|min:3',
                'sub_topic'  =>  'required',
                'category'  =>  'required', 
            ];

    }
}
```

After I make the validation using that class by making object in controller and my controller is as below:-

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Training;
 use App\User;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Http\Requests\TrainingRequest;
 use Request;


 class TrainingController extends Controller
{
public function store(TrainingRequest $request)
{
    //store Training

    //$training=Request::all();
    Training::create($request->all());
    return redirect('training');
}
```

Comment: what is the request file's encoding? is it UTF-8?

Comment: Its a php file. How to know the type of encoding of file ? Burak sir

Comment: see this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file

Comment: Yes, it is UTF-8 encoding

Comment: there must be spaces or some characters that you are missing, codes you posted are looking promising, i can't see any problems at all.

Comment: Thank you. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

there is a space before the starting php tag

solution just clear the space